# iTunes Connect: Invalid binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appcelerator

I am getting this error in `iTunes Connect`.

I have an app and I make some changes in that. So now I am uploading the updated version with the Organizer, but after upload, I am getting "**`invalid binary`**", but no more information.
Looking into this forum I found many people face same issue but no solution works for me.

I validate the app before uploading and the validate process is OK..
any advice will be welcome, this is driving me crazy.

thanks in advance.

`Titanium SDK 5.5.0` GA

`macOS Sierra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solve this problem.

In my app i use:
Version: 1.0.6
Build: 1.0.6

For some reason, now i cant do that, so i change the build version to:  106 and that makes the magic.

i hope this can help to others..

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you get an invalid binary error an email gets sent to the itunesConnect account, with the explanation on why it is invalid.

I did receive an invalid binary message and contained the following message:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

So it does have to do with a permission request. The way to fix this issue is to check the email, and explain why you are requesting access to that privacy-sensitive data. Keep in mind that we are not using Apple Music, but for some reason that showed up there ;)

Comment: This is a real solution. When status becomes *Invalid binary*, it sends email "App Store Connect: Your app "AppName" ... has one or more issues". The reason can be different and always described in email

Comment: Also it seems "ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement" isn't connected to *Invalid binary*

Answer (score 5):

I get this email from Apple:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSMicrophoneUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSCameraUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSAppleMusicUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

My App is using the camera, not Apple Music, not Agenda, etc... Maybe one of the Modules...

But anyway, I fixed it by adding this to tiapp.xml

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use to your contacts?</string>
            <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your camera?</string>
            <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your calendar?</string>
            <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we save to your library?</string>
            <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your microphone?</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

You can visit this page:

https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/09/ga-release-for-titanium-sdk-5-5-0-appcelerator-cli-5-5-0-appcelerator-studio-4-7-1/

I hope that helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? The OP made no mention of anything related to this information.

Comment: I received the invalid binary notification from the iTunes Connect app and no email at all. I validated the binary before uploading and that was successful. however shortly after uploading, i received the invalid binary. Adding the keys to the plist for the privacy permissions worked for me. I also had to localize the plist for all the languages i supported.

Comment: Thanks @Jovan in my case i only use one language.. and still no working..

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I uploaded the binary using Xcode Beta.  After uploading with the regular Xcode - it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error you will receive an email that explains why this error happened
It is possible that you are using deprecated API and classes and codes

Comment: Using deprecated APIs will never result in an "invalid binary" error.

Comment: it results invalid binary my app gets this error for deprecated API right now